# PHP call html alert box

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I'm working on a website. This site has a very cool `css alert boxes`. But the owner requested the box to be shown when a function is completed successfully!

**HTML ALERT**

```
   <div class="message-box message-box-info animated fadeIn" id="message-box-info">
        <div class="mb-container">
            <div class="mb-middle">
                <div class="mb-title"><span class="fa fa-info"></span> Information</div>
                <div class="mb-content">
                    <p>Welcome, <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></strong> </p>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg pull-right mb-control-close">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**BUTTON THAT TRIGGERS ALERT**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info mb-control" data-box="#message-box-info">Info</button>
```

So in `php` how could I trigger the alert with out using the button? - Thank you!

Comment: PHP is server side language. You should opt for Javascript/ jquery with AJAX

Comment: @Thamilan yes, but he is using php to complete a submitted form. When the form is completed successfully he wants that box above to be show.

Comment: I would look into what library is being used to display that alert and see if there is a function you can call to trigger the alert programatically.  Then just use PHP to output some javascript on the page to call that function.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
echo '</script>';
```

Here, in php echo javascript standard alert function is called.  Hope this helps..

Comment: thank you but we are not looking for a regular java script alert. The owner is looking for the usage of the code above.

Answer (score -1):

use script in php only after submitting the form.

```
echo '<script>$(".mb-control").trigger("click");<script>';
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but this code seems to lock the whole site and nothing happens after.

Comment: You might want to mention that your answer depends on jQuery, and that  this snippet must be triggered after jQuery is loaded and should be wrappen in an onload.....

Comment: Probably because of the `$` in the double quotes.

Answer (score -1):

To complete The Bigbyte Number 's post, without using jQuery :
(don't forget to add an ID to your button)

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("mybutton").onclick();</script>';
```

But Ajax would be a better solution.

Comment: The owner of the site does not want a button on the page. He wan't it so when the user submits a form it will show the ALERT.

Comment: You can set the button to "display: none" . Or try to find the function that show the dialog, to call it directly.